# Nexus GraphQl does not generate types when schema.prisma is changed

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, nexus-prisma

So, the core of the problem is described in title, but
When I commiting changes to schema.prisma my autogenerated export types in ./generated/nexus.ts don't refresh. I also don't see changes in apollo playground on my localhost:4000
I tried to migrate my schema and 'npx generate `path to my schema`' but they didn't work neither.
Without this I can't proceed with writing mutations and queries because TS can't see new types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to fix it, if any other faced with this problem so the solution can be found here https://github.com/prisma/prisma-examples/blob/latest/typescript/graphql-auth/README.md
The main issue was that you have to run your server after migration with db and after changes to schema.ts.